# jQuery Multiclasses function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create function that will do this same thing for 3 different classes. The only problem is that every time when I hove over any of the divs it affect all the others instead just one.

Could anyone advice me please how can I make it work separately for each class on hover stage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bbsa-h, .cscs-h, .dorbus-h").hover(function () {
    $(".bbsa, .cscs, .dorbus").stop().fadeTo(250, 0);
  }, function () {
    $(".bbsa, .cscs, .dorbus").stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
  });
```

});

Thank you for your help in advance.

Dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the divs have only one kind of subclass each, then it's pretty simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bbsa-h, .cscs-h, .dorbus-h").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".bbsa, .cscs, .dorbus").stop().fadeTo(250, 0);
  }, function () {
    $(this).find(".bbsa, .cscs, .dorbus").stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
  });
});
```

If they have multiple subclasses, you'll have to first check which class the current div belongs to and build the selector based on it.

Comment: This don't work I'm afraid. It is affecting parent classes which are : .bbsa-h, .cscs-h, .dorbus-h 

and I need to affect .bbsa, .cscs, .dorbus.

Any Help please?

Comment: Oh, I should have read your code a bit more carefully... fixed.